# Livesync with delete operation is not working

Tags: forgerock, openidm

Am using openidm , opendj as source and opendj as target
After enabling livesync delete operation is not working. Create , update are just working fine from source to target and vice versa. Can anyone help.

Configuration in behaviors, source missing to delete .

Regards,
sk

Comment: Do you have an association rule?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Sync Filter within your provisioner configuration. Make sure you aren't filtering out inactive records.

Comment: Jake,I didn't get you. When I delete the user in source it won't go to inactive stage right ? It should delete the record in target